# Trying to plot loglikelihood of Cauchy distribution for different values of theta in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the log-likelihood function of the Cauchy distribution for varying values of theta (location parameter). These are my observations:

```
obs<-c(1.77,-0.23,2.76,3.80,3.47,56.75,-1.34,4.24,3.29,3.71,-2.40,4.53,-0.07,-1.05,-13.87,-2.53,-1.74,0.27,43.21)
```

Here is my log-likelihood function:

```
ll_c<-function(theta,x_values){
  n<-length(x_values)
  logl<- -n*log(pi)-sum(log(1+(x_values-theta)^2))
  return(logl)
}
```

and Ive tried making a plot by using this code:

```
x<-seq(from=-10,to=10,by=0.1);length(x)
theta_null<-NULL
for (i in x){
  theta_log<-ll_c(i,counts)
  theta_null<-c(theta_null,theta_log)
}
plot(theta_null)
```

The graph does not look right and for some reason the length of x and theta_null differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `theta` is your location parameter (the scale is set to 1 in my example). You should obtain the same result using a `t-distribution` with 1 df and shifting the observations by `theta`. I left some comments in the code as guidance.

```
obs = c(1.77,-0.23,2.76,3.80,3.47,56.75,-1.34,4.24,3.29,3.71,-2.40,4.53,-0.07,-1.05,-13.87,-2.53,-1.74,0.27,43.21)

ll_c=function(theta, obs)
{   
    # Compute log-lik for obs and a value of thet (location)
    logl= sum(dcauchy(obs, location = theta, scale = 1, log = T)) 
    return(logl)
}

# Loop for possible values of theta(obs given)
x  = seq(from=-10,to=10,by=0.1)
ll = NULL
for (i in x)
{
    ll = c(ll, ll_c(i, obs))
}

# Plot log-lik vs possible value of theta 
plot(x, ll)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain how the for loop is looking for possible theta values given the observations?

Comment: The possibile values of theta are in the x vector. The loop goes through the values of the x vector and computes the likelihood for the ith possibile values (this is the meaning of the loop is for i in x). The observations are in the obs vector (like for your code). Please notice also that the way you wrote the loop in the question (i followed that in the answer) is not the most efficient, consider pre-allocation.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly what you are experiencing without more info. But I'll make an educated guess.

First of all, we can simplify this a lot by using the `*t` family of functions for the `t` distribution, as the cauchy distribution is just the `t` distribution with `df = 1`. So your calculations could've been done using

```
for(i in ncp)
  theta_null <- c(theta_null, sum(dt(values, 1, i, log = TRUE)))
```

Note that multiplying by `n` doesn't actually matter for any practical purposes. We are usually interested in minimizing/maximizing the likelihood in which case all constants are irrelevant.

Now if we use this approach, we can quite quickly notice something by printing the values:

```
print(head(theta_null))
[1] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf
```

So I am assuming what you are experiencing is that many of your values are "almost" negative infinity, and maybe these are not stored correctly in your outcome vector. I can't see that this should be the case from your code, but this would be my initial guess.